# how to find a path in non-binary tree python

Tags: python, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

How can I find the path from the root of the tree to a specific node, in a non-binary tree using python?

This is my code and it doesn't seem to work.

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val   = val
        self.up=None 
        self.down=None 
        self.left  = None
        self.right = None

    def findpath(root,end,path):    
        if root is None:
            path=[]
            return None 
        if root.val == end: 
            path.append(root.val) 
            return path 
        else: 
            path.append(root.val) 
            return findpath(root.up,end,path), findpath(root.down,end,path), findpath(root.left,end,path), findpath(root.right,end,path)
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- The `findpath` method's indentation suggests that this is a method of your `Tree` class, but you *call* it (recursively) as a stand alone function. So, it is not a method of your class and should have the indentation fixed. However, making it a method of the class would not be a bad idea.
- Your final `return` statement returns the result from *four* recursive calls, so it returns 4 values, where each of those 4 can itself represent 4 values (by recursion), etc... This is not right. The function should return one value: the path.
- `path.append` mutates the path that was provided by the caller. But the caller is not aware of that mutation, and passes the same path variable to another recursive call, expecting it to represent the *same* path as in the previous call. This is not true. So this has undesirable effects. You should let the paths be immutable, and pass newly constructed paths to recursive calls if that is necessary.
- The search will run in circles. You need to keep track of which nodes have already been visited and avoid that you visit them again.

I find it is easier to construct a path in the opposite direction: when the target is found, return an array with just that target-value. The caller can then add its cell to it and return *that*, ...etc.

Here `findpath` *is* a method of the `Tree` class:

```
def findpath(self, end):
    visited = set()  

    def dfs(node):
        if node is None or node in visited:
            return  # Failure
        if node.val == end:
            return [end]  # Success. This path that will be extended
        visited.add(node)  # Mark this node as visited
        path = dfs(node.up) or dfs(node.down) or dfs(node.left) or dfs(node.right)
        if path:
            path.append(node.val)
            return path

    path = dfs(self)
    if path:
        path.reverse()
        return path
```

The inner function (`dfs`) will return the path in reverse, so the outer one reverses it.

Important: this will not necessarily find the *shortest* path, just *a* path. If you need the shortest path, then you can better use a breadth-first search.

Comment: Any feed-back on this answer?